# How can Write Web driver command object on background color

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, nunit-3.0

I want to capture New Expiry Date (image attached)

Following code I tried

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[contains(@style,'background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);')]")));

return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(@style,'background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);')]"));
```

I got the element not the interactable error message. Please help me to resolve this.
I selected my element on the page (Yellow color highlighted) in the attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gso.png)

Comment: Can you share that HTML in text format ? or link to the page?

Comment: <td class="gridcell" style="background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);" aria-describedby="aaaca0c6-05dd-4b3b-b1ae-f79f6d42f64f" role="gridcell"></td>   this the selector which i want to capture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to have `style` attribute in your xpath. The reason is if the web developer change any color value

```
background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);
```

your xpath will fail. So we can say that it would be a brittle xpath.

But Since you've just shared this **HTML**

```
<td class="gridcell" style="background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);" aria-describedby="aaaca0c6-05dd-4b3b-b1ae-f79f6d42f64f" role="gridcell"></td>
```

You can use the below xpath

```
//td[@class='gridcell' and contains(@style,'background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);')]
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//td[@class='gridcell' and contains(@style,'background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This table/tr/td is not under an iframe.
2. This table/tr/tdis not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed Clarification. i Cant used your mentioned Xpath because there have 10 duplicate Values. Apart from that i cant used another attributes also there also have Duplicates .So How can i find my Element.Please Help me

Comment: Well as a last resort we have indexing `(//td[@class='gridcell' and contains(@style,'background-color:rgb(164 164 187 / 15%);')])[1]`, if [1] does not match your expected node, try to change that to `[2]` and 3,4, and so on..